# How to implement a periodically executed function in a Python web application?

Tags: python, mongodb, cron, fastapi

If an account is suspended for more than 7 days, it must be deleted in my case. Currently, I have three ideas:

- 1. Create an another cronjob folder and write a script to use cronjob to periodically execute this Python file. (Can I use the MongoDB connection method in `base.py` for sharing, or do I need to write it separately?)
- 2. Implement an API to delete accounts in `authentication.py` and set up a cronjob to periodically call this API.
- 3. Write the functionality in `user.py` and use `if __name__ == "__main__":` to call that function.

     (You can check function `delete_suspended_accounts` below.)

What would be the best practices to implement this functionality? Or do you have other suggestions? Thank you.

For more information, you can check my code structure.

1. Implement account APIs in `authentication.py`, such as registration, password reset, account suspension, account reactivation, and account blocking.
2. Implement MongoDB connection in `base.py`.
3. Implement database logic operations for account APIs in `user.py`.

```
.
└── fastapi-backend
    ├── assets
    ├── static
    ├── src
    │   ├── api
    │   │   ├── api_router.py
    │   │   └── authentication.py
    │   ├── db
    │   │   ├── base.py
    │   │   └── user.py
    │   ├── models
    │   └── services
    └── utils
```

#### base.py

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import urllib
from fastapi import Depends
from src.core.config import setting
from typing import Callable, Type

class Base:
    def __init__(self, connection: MongoClient) -> None:
        self._conn = connection.demo

    @property
    def connection(self):
        return self._conn


def _get_mongo_client():
    return MongoClient(setting.MONGO_URL, maxPoolSize=None)


def get_repository(repo_type: Type[Base]) -> Callable:
    async def _get_repo(conn: MongoClient = Depends(_get_mongo_client)):
        yield repo_type(conn)
    return _get_repo
```

#### user.py

```
class UserRepository(Base):

    def __init__(self, conn):
        super().__init__(conn)

    def suspend_user(self, user_id: str):
        the_user = self.connection.user.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(user_id)})
        if the_user and the_user['status'] == Status.ACTIVATED.value:
            self.connection.user.update(the_user, {"$set": {'status': Status.SUSPENDED.value,
                                                            'suspended_date': datetime.datetime.now()}})
        else:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=u'Not Activated')

    def delete_suspended_accounts(self):
        query = {"status": 'Status.SUSPENDED.value', "suspended_date": {"$lt": datetime.datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=7)}}
        result = self.connection.user.delete_many(query)
        return result.deleted_count
```

### authentication.py

```
@authentication.post('/suspend')
async def suspend_account(request: Request, token: str,
                 user_repository: UserRepository = Depends(get_repository(UserRepository))):
    try:
        # decode access token
        access_token = jwt.decode(token, key=setting.SECERT_KEY)
        # suspend user
        user_id = access_token['sub']
        user_repository.suspend_user(user_id=user_id)
    except DecodeError:
        return {'message': 'decode error'}
    except ExpiredSignatureError:
        return {'message': 'expired signature error'}
    return {'message': 'ok'}
```

I tried the first method as follows, writing a script and then executing it with a cronjob, which worked successfully. However, my tech leader suggested that I write it in `user.py`. But since FastAPI uses dependency injection (Depends) to connect to MongoDB, how should I write it for the best approach? Or are there any other methods you would recommend? Thank you.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

client = MongoClient("MONGO_URL")
db = client['demo']
collection = db['user']
def delete_suspended_accounts():
    query = {"status": 3, "suspended_date": {"$lt": datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=7)}}
    result = collection.delete_many(query)
    print(f"Deleted {result.deleted_count} suspended accounts.")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    delete_suspended_accounts()
```

Comment: Why DI is any problem?

Comment: I don't have an issue with dependency injection. The problem is that the original API retrieves the MongoDB connection through dependency injection. Now, I need to use a cron job to periodically execute a certain function while still utilizing the MongoDB connection. How should I go about writing this?

Comment: Write a cron script, call `_get_mongo_client` directly and create your service from what gets returned - since `Depends` doesn't get resolve, you just have to create the functions they reference yourself.

Comment: @MatsLindh I applied it as follows. Please take a look at the answers below. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I created another folder called cronjob and placed `delete_account.py` inside it. You can just browse the code below.

```
.
└── fastapi-backend
    ├── assets
    ├── static
    ├── cronjob
    │   └── delete_account.py
    ├── src
    │   ├── api
    │   │   ├── api_rounter.py
    │   │   └── authentication.py
    │   ├── db
    │   │   ├── base.py
    │   │   └── user.py
    │   ├── models
    │   └── services
    └── utils
```

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../')

from src.db.users import UserRepository
from src.db.base import _get_mongo_client

conn = _get_mongo_client()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    user_repo = UserRepository(conn)
    counts = user_repo.delete_suspended_accounts()
    print(f"Deleted {counts} suspended accounts.")
```

I have no idea if using `import sys` to change path is the best practice or not, but it seems to work.

Comment: If you're going to manipulate the import path, you probably want to use `os.path.dirname(__file__)` or something similar, as you're otherwise bound to having the `cronjob` directory as your current working directory (so using an absolute path or running it from the project directory will make the path different)

Comment: I would prefer to create these as packages so that imports can work instead of manipulating the `sys.path`